# How to exclude an input if a certain value is entered

Tags: python

I have done this code:

```
Num = int(input("Enter a large number: "))
Num2 = Num+10
print("If I added 10 to your number it would be:" , Num2)
print("The new number times 2 would be " , Num2*2)
count = 0
number = Num
while (number > 1):
  number = number//10
  count = count + 1
  i = 1
  for i in range(1,count+1):
  Num = Num+1*(10**i)
  i = i+1
print("adding one to every digit on your first number would be: " , Num + 1)
```

In this code I would like to end it if the integer 9 is in the value entered by the user.
I do not know how 
Please help

If 9 is entered the code should just end and ouTPUT 9 IS INVALID

Comment: What do you do if I type 99 ?

Comment: Do you want to exclude all values containing the digit 9, or just exclude the value 9 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the user input num is `9` and exit with a message.

```
Num = int(input("Enter a large number: "))    
if Num == 9:
   print("Invalid Input")
   exit()
else:
    Num2 = Num + 10
    print("If I added 10 to your number it would be:", Num2)
    print("The new number times 2 would be ", Num2 * 2)
    count = 0
    number = Num
    while (number > 1):
        number = number // 10
        count = count + 1
        i = 1
        for i in range(1, count + 1):
            Num = Num + 1 * (10 ** i)
        i = i + 1
    print("adding one to every digit on your first number would be: ", Num + 1)
```

OR if the intention is to check if there is `9` in the input.

```
Num = str(input("Enter a large number: "))
if "9" in Num:
    print("Invalid Inputs")
    exit()
```

Comment: it doesn't work as in when it adds one every time it does something very random now

Comment: @Samardeep Khurana what doesn't work? And what do you mean by it does something very random? Kindly elaborate on what input you give to which it doesn't work.

Comment: if i enter the value 1111 it says that adding 1 to each digit is 2468 or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Check if `Num = 9` than execute `os.exit(1)`

```
Num = int(input("Enter a large number: "))
if Num == 9:
    exit()
Num2 = Num+10
print("If I added 10 to your number it would be:" , Num2)
print("The new number times 2 would be " , Num2*2)
count = 0
number = Num
while (number > 1):
  number = number//10
  count = count + 1
  i = 1
  for i in range(1,count+1):
  Num = Num+1*(10**i)
  i = i+1
print("adding one to every digit on your first number would be: " , Num + 1)
```

Comment: OP asks if 9 is `IN` the value, not if 9 `IS` the value

Answer (score 0):

To exclude all values containing the digit 9 check into the string before converting it to an integer like so :

```
num_str = str(input("Enter a large number: "))
if "9" in num_str:
    print("Value contains a 9. This is invalid")
    exit()
num = int(num_str)

 ...
```

To exclude only the value 9, check for this specific value:

```
num = int(input("Enter a large number: "))
if num == 9:
    print("Value is 9. This is invalid")
    exit()

...
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do this

```
Num = int(input("Enter a large number: "))
if Num==9:
    print("9 is incorrect")
else:

    Num2 = Num+10
    print("If I added 10 to your number it would be:" , Num2)
    print("The new number times 2 would be " , Num2*2)
    count = 0
    number = Num
    while (number > 1):
      number = number//10
      count = count + 1
      i = 1
      for i in range(1,count+1):
      Num = Num+1*(10**i)
      i = i+1
    print("adding one to every digit on your first number would be: " , Num + 1)
```

hope it helps

Comment: No it doesnt help

Comment: why ? I thinks thats what he wants